# ASP.Net MVC ListBoxFor - Let user add items

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My application currently consists of a few classes - Ill show you the important ones:

Entry

```
public class Entry{
    public IEnumerable<Hardware> RequestedHardware {get; set;}
}

public class Hardware{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public bool IsAvailable {get; set;}
}
```

When creating a new Dataset (new Entry) I want the user to be able to add new Hardware devices to this Entry (a Listbox to show the currently added and a Textbox with a button to add the "device" to the listbox). All added devices should be transferred to the Create Post Method in my Controller after clicking on the Submit button.

I've totally no idea what to search for and no idea how to start here - is it even possible?

If I had to guess I'd say I have to use a @Html.ListBoxFor but as I said I'm not sure about that.

**Edit 1**

I'll try to explain step-by-step:

1. A User clicks on the New Item Button on the Index Page
2. The new Page with empty fields for several data (not explained here) and an empty listbox (for Hardware.Name strings) will be loaded
3. A user is able to add n Hardware items using a Textbox and a Button. On Button click the entered string in the textbox should be added to the listbox (Client-Side)
4. After the user entered all data and clicked on the submit-button the data should be sent to the Create Controller Method (the model I use is "Entry" which is not explained here. Entry has some properties such as an Person object (containing all person data) and the above mentioned List.)

I will add all models needed to explain this situation this afternoon.

**Edit 2**

Model

```
public class Entry{
    public Employee Employee {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<Hardware> Hardware {get; set;} 
}

public class Employee{
    public string Firstname {get; set;}
    public string Lastname {get; set;}
}


public class Hardware{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public bool IsAvailable {get; set;}
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(Entry entry){
    //I want to be able to access entry.Hardware here
}
```

Html - The user (viewer of the page) can create a new Entry - this Entry consists of an Employee and n Hardware.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" class="info">
                Hardware data
            </th>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ListBoxFor(o => o.Hardware, xxx) @* Here all Hardware the User adds should be shown *@
            </td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.Hardware.Name) @* If a user wants to add a new Hardware here he has to add its text *@
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Hardware"/> @* To save the above entered Hardware click here *@
            </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Edit 3**

```
<input type="text" id="my-textbox">
                @Html.ListBoxFor(o => o.RequestedHardware, new List<SelectListItem>())
                <a href='#' class="btn btn-primary action-add-to-list">Add Text To List</a>

                    <script>
                        $('.action-add-to-list').click(function () {
                            var newListValue = $('#my-textbox').val();
                            if ($.trim(newListValue) != '')
                            {
                                $('#RequestedHardware').append('<option>' + newListValue + '</option>');
                                $('#RequestedHardware').val('');
                            }
                        });
                    </script>
```

This solves my problem partially - Now I want to be able to transfer all 's as objects of Type Hardware (the option-text is the value of Hardware.Name, Hardware.IsAvailable should be always false)

Is there a proper solution?

Comment: Your question is unclear.. The first part of your question is about the controller.. and then the last part deals with Razor which is for the view... so do you need help with allowing users to add hardware? Or do you need help with displaying the available hardware?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid Some new information has been added - I hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about is a combo box, which lets you type or select from an existing list. You can't use a listbox for this. You need a regular text field. The existing items will either be provided by a datalist (if you can use HTML5) or an AJAX query.

An example of using datalist:

```html
<label>
    Hardware
    <input list="hardware" name="hardware" />
</label>
<datalist id="hardware">
  <option value="Hammer">
  <option value="Nails">
  <option value="Wrench">
  <option value="Pliers">
  <option value="Screwdriver">
  <option value="Drill">
</datalist>
```

The only issue is that this is new in HTML 5, so your users will need to be using modern browsers that support it. Although, you can use a polyfill to add support to at least some lesser browsers. Here's [one such polyfill](https://css-tricks.com/relevant-dropdowns-polyfill-for-datalist/). There's probably others.

Alternatively, you can just use [any random combo box JavaScript plugin](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript%20combo%20box&ia=web) out there.

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I'm looking for - I will add further details to my question asap. Thanks for your answer anyway :)

Comment: I've added some new information - It'd be very kind if you could re-read the question - ty :)